# Gathering TFS records across multiple projects

Tags: version-control, tfs, history

So, I am new to using TFS queries but I have a requirement to put together a query that gathers all history information, Work items, and tasks across 4 projects. Does TFS allow me define my own variable? We are given @ME, @Project, etc, but can I create others? Also wanted to know how I can reference all four separate Projects in just the, I guess Master project site? Thanks in advance.

Comment: can't you just take out the "Where project = @project" part of the query?

Comment: Would that not cause TFS to then search all of the projects on our server account? Maybe more than 100 of them

Comment: You could instead do "where project = 'project1' or project = 'project2'" etc for the 4 projects you need included in your query

Comment: Tried that but that only returned me the list in the current project.

Comment: The @Project refers to the project where the query is saved. If you want to query WIs in other projects then I think what you need is WHERE PortfolioProject IN ('Project1', 'Project2', 'Project3') AND [...]

Answer (score 0):

Work Item Query Language has only two macros: `@me` and `@today`. The `@project` macro is defined by the UI.
When using the API, you must define `@project` by yourself, but you can add your own variables.

See [Query for Bugs, Tasks, and Other Work Items](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb130306.aspx) for complete details.

Answer (score 0):

You should probably be looking at the Data Warehouse and Cube to solve your reporting issue.

Its old but still valid: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff647430.aspx

You can create a reporting services report that has basically whatever you want from tfs in whatever format you want.